# not opening the page that is being called

Tags: php

I have this in my checkout.php file when i submit data then with value Paypal then it is opening the page( edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php) in XAMP but when i set this site online it is not opening this page but it automatically moves to (pay_eway.php).You can check this site online through this link http://taratrampolines.com.au/tramponline/

```
 if($form_submit == "Paypal") 
        {//echo "<script>alert('Please fill the form.')</script>";
            header("Location: edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php");} 
        else    
        {
            echo'<script>window.location="pay_eway.php";</script>';}

    //  if($form_submit == "Paypal")    header("Location: pay.php");
    if($form_submit == "eway") 
        {       header("Location: pay_eway.php");}
        else
            {//echo //"<script>alert('Please fill the form.')</script>";
            echo'<script>window.location="pay_eway.php";</script>';
    }
```

Comment: This page link `edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php` looks suspicious.

Comment: And I don't understand why you have two different redirection methods with PHP and JS when `header` seems to do everything you need.

Comment: @AlanMachado So your point is this is causing problem...?

Comment: My first point is to understand why you are using it. You may have reasons I didn't get from your question. Then, we work on the possibilities, like simplifying your code to reduce probable error causes.

Comment: not this link edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php  is't suspecious i want to send data to paypal site through this page...

Comment: actually i am not using it i am just correcting this behaviour of site...

Comment: Ok, try cutting off the fat: `switch($form_submit) { case "Paypal":            header("Location: edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php"); break; case "eway": header("Location: pay_eway.php"); break; default:       echo '<script>window.location="pay_eway.php";</script>';}`

Comment: @AlanMachado its not working again it opening pay_eway.php.and gives the error ( cannot modify header information - headers already sent)

Comment: That's because you can't have any output data before sending `header`s, check if it is the case.

Comment: yes @AlanMachado you ARE right there was echo statements that were not commented properly.. thnx

Comment: Do we have an answer then? Or you still having the same problems?

Comment: my problem is solved by removing unnecessary echo statements...

Answer (score 1):

Check your code previous to your `header` sending conditionals. You **must not** send any kind of output **before** sending `headers` or you'll face an exception.