# submitting form by not going to another page

Tags: php

```
switch($form_submit) { case "Paypal": header("Location: edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php"); break; case "eway": header("Location: pay_eway.php"); break; default: echo '<script>window.location="pay_eway.php";</script>';}
```

i have this code in my file (checkout.php)
now i don't want to move onto this page (edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php).and to submit my vaalues through this.
this page(edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php) contains this

```
    <body>

<section class="trampoline-products">
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="taranayadav@gmail.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
 <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $usrDet['fname'];?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $usrDet['lname'];?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php echo $usrDet['state'];?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php echo $usrDet['pcode'];?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $usrDet['email'];?>" data-type="email">
 <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $usrDet['phone'];?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Tara Trampolines Payment">
<input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $orderDet['id'];?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.oyasisspring.com/tara/success_paypal.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $orderDet['order_total'];?>">
                        <script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>tion 6 End -->
</form>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: You have to use ajax call for this to submit value and you can identify by jquery on which page you have to submit values

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719690/not-opening-the-page-that-is-being-called/32721767#32721767) you were struggling to find a way to be redirected, and now you don't want it anymore?

Comment: so in which part of my (checkout.php) file i have to put this form.

Comment: yes @AlanMachado you are right

Comment: @AlanMachado so what i have to do now ?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you submit the form? What kind of return, **or none at all**?

Comment: i just want to move this page (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr)  with form data. u can check online by visiting this site(http://taratrampolines.com.au/tramponline/) when u click on checout with paypal so it load the page (edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php) and then move to this page(https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr)

Comment: this file (edADHJASHDIJHashiuas39wed9jsdcud.php) contains the form that i posted above in question

Comment: Could you make your filenames a bit more cryptic, please?

Comment: @mastov no i can't. because i think there is no need here

Comment: @AlanMachado waiting for your solution?

Comment: Where is your PayPal Gateway API implementation?